# IF Fields: how to exclude an entire block of content?

Tags: microsoft-word, mail-merge

I'd like to use an IF field to toggle if a section is shown or not. I know how it works if you want to show different text depending on a value:

```
{ IF { MERGEFIELD doShowThis \* MERGEFORMAT } = "1" "Yes" "No" \* MERGEFORMAT }
```

But what I want to toggle is more complex than a simple text change. It's an entire section that could have different text formatting or tables, and the content of that section uses MergeFields. Ideally, I'd like to do something like this:

[image]

Is it possible to use IF fields this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Save your large, formatted blocks of text as AutoText or another Building Block and have AutoText fields in your If Field.

There are limits to how much text you want in an If Field, both in what Word can handle and in how much you want to handle. This can get confusing!

AutoText (and other Building Blocks) can handle a massive amount of text including page or even Section breaks. This can be brought into your document with a simple field: the [AutoText Field](https://support.microsoft.com/office/47082137-225a-4d9e-b74a-5faf6a5f69cb).

Set up and format the text you want for your truetext and your falsetext in a document using the same styles. Select them and save them as AutoText or another Building Block in your document's template.

Here is a [basic page from Microsoft on saving such text](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-reusable-text-snippets-0bc40cab-f49c-4e06-bcb2-cd43c1674d1b). Here is [my writing on how to do it](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#StoreBuildingBlocks). Essentially, you select what you want saved and press a keyboard shortcut (**Alt+F3** on most Windows versions), pick a template to save it in and use a standard category or assign your own. You want a meaningful name that will not be accidentally typed. The name must start with a letter, not a number or symbol. The name suggested by Word when you save is seldom the best one to use.

The [AutoText Field](https://support.microsoft.com/office/47082137-225a-4d9e-b74a-5faf6a5f69cb) can be inserted using the Insert > Quick Parts > Field or it can be typed and inserted using another keyboard shortcut. For an AutoText entry named `ExecSecond` one way to insert an AutoText field would be to type `AutoText ExecSecond` then select this and press **Ctrl+F9** to create a *field* with those contents.

It would look like this: `{ AutoText ExecSecond }`. This should be your *truetext* or *falsetext* in your If Field.

*Note that you can save as a different kind of Building Block in the Windows versions of Word. The AutoText field will call those just as easily as an AutoText entry.*

**References:**

- [If Field](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#IF_field) (my webpage)
- [If Field](https://support.microsoft.com/office/9f79e82f-e53b-4ff5-9d2c-ae3b22b7eb5e) (Microsoft page)
- [AutoText Field](https://support.microsoft.com/office/47082137-225a-4d9e-b74a-5faf6a5f69cb) (Microsoft page)
- [Saving Text Snippets](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-reusable-text-snippets-0bc40cab-f49c-4e06-bcb2-cd43c1674d1b) (Microsoft page)
- [Saving Building Blocks](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#StoreBuildingBlocks) (on my page)
- [My writing on Global Templates](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm#Global)
- My article on the Microsoft website about [Dealing With Fields](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/dealing-with-fields-in-microsoft-word/e1bdddad-5a51-4327-837c-c3786c16a501)

**Caveats:**

1. AutoText (and other Building Blocks) is stored in templates. The user of your document prior to the decision made by the IF Field must have that template active. It must either be the document's attached template or it must be a loaded [global template](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm#Global).
2. If the document is being sent out away from the source template, the AutoText Fields must be locked or unlinked.
3. If you want to change anything that is in the AutoText you must either recreate the AutoText entry (long term) or unlink the field in your document and then make the change. Any changes you make to it while it is in field form will disappear when the field is updated.

Here is my article on the Microsoft website about [Dealing With Fields](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/dealing-with-fields-in-microsoft-word/e1bdddad-5a51-4327-837c-c3786c16a501). It goes into more about the keyboard shortcuts and how to lock or unlink fields. The Mac version of Word uses slightly different shortcuts and many computers require the addition of the ***Fn*** key to shortcuts involving the Function keys.

Comment: That sounds interesting and might be the solution to my problem, but I have to ask, since I can't try it right now: can I still use MergeFields within the AutoText fields? Because the content of the two blocks is dynamic (something I probably should've mentioned...), so if that's not possible, I can't use it.

Comment: Yes. you could nest the name of the AutoText entry in an AutoText field and skip the IF field altogether  `{ AutoText { Mergefield EntryName } }` or you can test on the MergeField content to decide which AutoText entry to use. Can the AutoText entry contain MergeFields? I think so but have not tried it lately. Try with a small sample.

Comment: I've tested and an AutoText field that contains merge codes works. I also tried putting two different ones as truetext and falsetext inside an IF Field testing a mergefield. Works for me here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. While your solution does work, I can't really use it myself because the template is supposed to be used by an automated system that doesn't have access to the AutoTexts - something I didn't mention on purpose so the answer can be more general. Regardless, I found another solution to that problem (for now...), so I accepted your answer.